# HttpURLConnection: how to read the answer

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I'm going nuts on this. (as most people posting here lol)

I have a server written by somebody else and I'm sending request to it to retrieve info.

I know that it works because I have some webpages that the other programmer used to test.

I would like to ask the question to the guy directly but since he lives in Japan and my in Spain its a bit complicated to communicate

my request works fine and I get the right response code but then I'm stuck, I don't know how to read the HttpURLConnection object to get the content.

in the web browser I get simply :

```
DOC_FOUND
ID
5
AUTHOR
adrian
TITLE
the adrian
DESCRIPTION
```

I tried **getHeaderFields** and **getInputStream** with no luck (I might be using them wrong)

Any ideas ?

Jason

Comment: haha we have no idea what this invisble code looks like, or what you are going.... good luck?

Comment: No real question here.  Could you try to be clearer with what you're exactly asking and trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your input stream with some kind of reader.

```
BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlcon.getInputStream()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Without code the best I can do is point you to a tutorial of how to properly connect.  Maybe you will notice your error:

[how-open-url-read-contents-httpurl-connection-java](http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/java/how-open-url-read-contents-httpurl-connection-java)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a simple wrapper around URLConnection that does all the heavy-lifting for you?
With [Resty](http://beders.github.com/Resty/Resty/Overview.html) it could be as simple as:

```
new Resty().text(url).toString();
```

if your content is plain text;

** DISCLAIMER: I'm the author of this free, open-source library. **